# WPF Combo Box Binding / ObservableCollection Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, observablecollection

Having trouble with combo box binding;

i have an Observable Collection that looks like this;

[image]

Here is what my Combo box looks like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding settingsViewModel.sFTPs}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Folder"
      SelectedValuePath="Folder"
      SelectedValue="{Binding settingsViewModel.sFTPs[0].Folder}"
      Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"
      md:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"
      md:HintAssist.Hint="Save Directory"
      md:HintAssist.FloatingScale="1.5"
      Margin="5"
      />
```

it returns the list of items fine but when i try and save it does this;

```
[SFTP Connection]
Host=
Port=
UserName=
Password=
Type=SFTP
SavePath=Folder1
```

here is my save Method:

```
private void ExecuteSaveCommand(object param)
{

    IniFile iniFile = new IniFile();

    iniFile.Load(@"Configuration.ini");

    foreach (var itemCollection in sFTPs)
    {
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[0].Value = itemCollection.Address;
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[1].Value = itemCollection.Port;
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[2].Value = itemCollection.UserName;
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[3].Value = itemCollection.Password;
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[4].Value = "SFTP";
        iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[5].Value = itemCollection.Folder;
    }
    iniFile.Save(@"Configuration.ini");
}
```

Comment: `{Binding settingsViewModel.sFTPs}` requires that there is a public `settingsViewModel` property in the current DataContext of the ComboBox.

Comment: There is indeed a public SettingsViewModel just seems whenever i click save this will take the last ObservableCollection object and save it regardless of what combo box item i select.

Comment: anyone with anymore idea's?

Comment: Are you intentionally binding the SelectedValue to the Folder property of the first object in sFTPs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending new elements, the code for creating a section overrides the same section over and over using the current element. This results in only the last element being saved.

```
foreach (var itemCollection in sFTPs)
{
    // iniFile.Sections[0] <-- always overrides the same section
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[0].Value = itemCollection.Address;
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[1].Value = itemCollection.Port;
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[2].Value = itemCollection.UserName;
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[3].Value = itemCollection.Password;
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[4].Value = "SFTP";
    iniFile.Sections[0].Keys[5].Value = itemCollection.Folder;
}
```